# add two date using datetime php class

Tags: php, date, datetime

I need to add **30 days** with **2014-03-06**.

I've done below code:-

```
$due_dt = new DateTime("2014-03-06");
$act_dt = $due_dt->add("+30 days");
```

This code giving below error:-

```
Message: DateTime::add() expects parameter 1 to be DateInterval, string given
```

Any help please...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reading the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and/or the error message would have provided the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`DateTime::modify`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php)

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-03-06');
$date->modify('+30 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 3):

try

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
```

for more info :- http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$due_dt->modify('+30 days');
```

However if you want to use the add function,

```
$due_dt->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
$due_dt= strtotime ('+30 day' , strtotime ($date));
```